# Como fechar aplicativo ao clicar em um Dialog na MainActivity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

O meu app tem várias activitys.

Algumas delas tem um Dialog que ao clicar nele, o aplicativo volta para a MainActivity.

Eu quero que quando clicar em sim no Dialog da MainActivity, o aplicativo seja fechado.

O que acontece é que quando eu clico em sim, o aplicativo volta para a activity que foi aberta anteriormente.

**Como faço para fechar o app clicando no dialog da MainActivity?**

Comment: Coloque o código da sua MainActivity para a gente saber o que você fez de errado.

Answer (score 1):

A função abaixo encerra de maneira simples, e ainda limpa toda a máquina java dedicada à execução do aplicativo. No entanto, você deve chamá-la a partir da atividade principal, caso contrário, o Android pode reiniciar seu aplicativo automaticamente. (Testado isso no Android 7.0). Ele deve encerra instantaneamente o processo do Linux e todos os threads do aplicativo.

Chame essa função do seu Dialog:

```
public void exit(){
  System.exit(0);
}
```

Ele instantaneamente faz uma boa saída sem informar ao usuário que o aplicativo falhou.

Comment: eu já tinha usado isso. não funcionou. é porque como é um quiz, inicia na tela principal, vai pra tela de pergunta e pra tela de certo/errado e volta pra tela de pergunta. fica indo e vindo nessas duas telas e todas elas tem um Dialog que, se clicar em sim, na tela pergunta e certo/errado, coloquei um startActivity pra voltar pra tela principal e também apagar os pontos do banco, e na tela principal, se clicar em sim, quero que encerre de vez o app. mas quando clico ele volta pra tela pergunta.